# non-zero symmetric, upper-triangular matrix

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am to give an example of a non-zero symmetric, upper-triangular matrix of size 4.

I thought upper-triangle means the values in the lower matrix would be 0's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** any diagonal matrix will do.

Comment: Well almost any

Answer (score 0):

symmetric and upper triangular means all the non diagonal elements has to be zero

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me. I thought it was saying I couldn't use any 0's.